# Does getting Secure Token from "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com" work with localhost ?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to implement  PayPal Payments Pro(PayFlow Edition) with PayPal hosted checkout pages and getting error "java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server" on httpPost request from java API to "pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com".

However, performing following CURL operation(using -k to ignore ssl) works:
curl https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com -kd "VENDOR=myAccountId&USER=myUserName&PWD=myPwd&PARTNER=PayPal&TRXTYPE=S&AMT=20.00&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=tokenId&CURRENCY=USD&BILLTOSTRET=1121 Ram Ct&BILLTOZIP=95131"

but removing 'k' results in ssl cert error:

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

Is there a way to make request calls to https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com from API on local host ? Or ssl certificate is required even for development environment ?